# News that can deflect a blow

Tags: riddle, word

*News that can deflect a blow


Half the world or so misheard


Delivered through a short window


Pray what am I? A single word ...*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Mail

News that can deflect a blow

> Chain mail can deflect a blow. There are many newspapers called the Mail.

Half the world or so misheard

> Roughly half the world's population is male (or mail misheard)

Delivered through a short window

> Mail is delivered through a letterbox which is a short window.

Prey what am I? A single word ...

> Mail is a single word.

Comment: Got it in one. I obviously need to make a harder one next time.